# Avoid overwriting dataset in Python forloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
price
date            price      fruit
2010-01-04    0.83        banana
2010-01-04    0.05         apple
```

For each fruit, how could you keep if that fruit ==True, and then drop the fruit column temporarily when dealing with that particular fruit?

```
listxx = [(price, "price")]
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']

for fruit in fruits:
    for x, y in listxx:
            x[x['fruit'] == fruit]
            x.drop(['fruit'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Currently, when I get to banana, the fruit column is already deleted because of apple.

When iterating over banana, the price dataset should look be:

```
date          price     
2010-01-04    0.83
```

When iterating over apple, the price dataset should look be:

```
date            price    
2010-01-04    0.05
```

Comment: The question is not clear, if you intend to drop the fruit column or a row.

Comment: Could you show exactly what the output should look line for a given input, and make the output big enough to show the problem (i.e., include both things that should and shot not be removed)?

Comment: It needs to iterate for each fruit. The code breaks because there is no fruit column to drop by the time it gets to the second item in the list. The keep if fruit=True and dropping of the fruit column is temporary.

Comment: This part: `x[x['fruit'] == fruit]` creates a *new* table with only the rows where the `fruit` matches, and then *throws it away with no meaningful effect*. In particular, the `x` on the next line refers to the *original* `price` table.

Comment: "It needs to iterate for each fruit." This is *not nearly enough information*. What is supposed to *happen* during the iteration? It seems like you want to find the rows where the fruit matches, and consider those rows without the fruit column, and... then what? Are you trying to change the contents of the `price` dataframe at all?

Comment: "When iterating over banana, the price dataset should look be" Okay; do you *actually want to change the original table to this*, or do you want to *create a new, temporary table* with only that data? Because if you take all of that data out of the original table, then of course you're going to have problems putting it back; how are you supposed to know what was taken out in order to put it back?

Comment: I need the price dataset to temporarily remove firm column and keep if fruit = that fruit. Then go back to the original dataset for the next fruit to do the same.

Comment: Right, so, the easiest way to do that is to create a new dataset with the filtered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the price dataset to temporarily remove firm column and keep if fruit = that fruit. Then go back to the original dataset for the next fruit to do the same.

Practically speaking, this means making a *new* dataset with the filtered data. We'll give it a separate name, so that we can i) actually refer to the result from checking the rows, and ii) drop the columns from that result, instead of the original result.

We'll also put some effort into naming things in a way that makes it easy to understand what's what.

```
tables_and_names = [(price, "price")]
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']

for fruit in fruits:
    for table, name in tables_and_names:
        filtered_table = table[table['fruit'] == fruit]
        filtered_table.drop(['fruit'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        # now we can do more logic with the filtered_table
```